# I want to use Native.js to check whether the local network permission of IOS is enabled

Tags: ios

I want to know the status of local network permissions in IOS

Now I probably use：

var NEVPNManager = plus.ios.importClass("NEVPNManager");
var vpnManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager();

I don't know if this is correct or not.